# Transcoding DV Without Desyncs

Tags: video, audio

I've recorded DV video from my camcorder over FireWire, and it plays fine in OSX. However, when trying to transcode it to H.264 for editing and uploading it to YouTube, the audio desyncs. I've been using iMovie to record from my camcorder and then Handbrake to do the encoding with default settings. How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: At what rate does the sync drift? A second every few minutes?  Faster?  Also, are you recording NTSC (US) or PAL (Other Countries) video?

Comment: It drifts about 5 seconds over the 20 minute video. If it matters, the audio is faster than the video. I'm recording with NTSC, and according to QuickTime, both videos are 29.97 FPS.

Comment: Does Handbrake give you a choice as to the samplerate of the audio? I used to have no end of trouble encoding my own DivX ;-) and XviD files many years ago when I was first learning the ropes - best to keep your audio samplerate as 48kHz as opposed to the audio default of 44.1kHz. Not a frequent Handbrake user so can't recall if it defaults to 'sensible' settings (it should...)  Failing that, what format are you saving to when you dump through iMovie? Have you considered an alternate intermediary codec if iMovie offers one?

Comment: Christopher- I'm exporting it from iMovie (HD, not the newest version) as MPEG-4. I just tried exporting at 48KHz from both iMovie and Handbrake and neither worked. I'm not sure about intermediary formats but the few I've tried have suffered the same issue.